# No nic with thid ID () is registered with this ConnectionManager, return empty GateList

Tags: omnet++, veins

I use Veins-4a2 and I have changed the car.ned and its nicType by specifying

**string nicType = default("Nic802154_TI_CC2420");**

When I run the simulation, I get this window with the following message "**Module RSUExampleScenario.node[0].nic.phy: No nic with thid ID (9) is registered with this ConnectionManager, return empty GateList.**":

[[image: [1]]

What this message means and how can I adjust it please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simulation module you are using was not written to support creation of new modules during runtime. Veins is creating a new module whenever a new car starts driving. This is different to most other network simulations where all nodes are already present at the start of the simulation.

As the simulation module you are using (`Nic802154_TI_CC2420`) is not part of Veins, I cannot say how you can change the module to support creation during runtime.

Comment: Thank you Sir for your response, I have re used the simulation module of veins "Nic80211p" with "Host802154_2400MHz.ned" which is a sensor node from WSNRouting example of Mixim. Now I had this error: cListener destructor: listener at address 089a0f70 is still added to 1 listener list(s). This will likely result in a crash: Listeners must be fully unsubscribed before deletion. Trying to determine components where this listener is subscribed..   What mean this error please?

Comment: And knowing that I used the application layer "sensorAppLayer" of SNRouting example of Mixim instead of "TraCIDemo11p".